tensorflow Input shape error: Expected shape (None, 3), but input has incompatible shape (None, 3, 3)
After adding tf.dataset generator, the model.fit() starts to throw error about incompatible input shape. The model is a VGG16 transfer learning model with customized dense layer. The input is image of shape (224, 224, 3), along with a user id. The output is a user id along with a binary flag. Here is the model def:
def model_compile_image_binary_late_embedding(num_user_ids, embedding_dim=50):
    image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image_input')
    base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=image_input)
    
    # Freeze the pre-trained layers
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
        
    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.55)(x)
   
    # User ID input and embedding
    user_id_input = Input(shape=(num_user_ids,), name='user_id_input')
    user_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=num_user_ids, output_dim=embedding_dim)(user_id_input)
    user_embedding_flattened = Flatten()(user_embedding)
    
    concatenated = Concatenate()([x, user_embedding_flattened]) #<<==input includes user id
    
    # Output layers
    output_user = Dense(num_user_ids, activation='softmax', name='user_output', dtype='float32')(concatenated)
    output_binary = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='binary_output', dtype='float32')(concatenated)
    
    model = Model(inputs=[image_input, user_id_input], outputs=[output_user, output_binary])
    
    # Set the Adam optimizer with reduced learning rate
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0002) # Original is 0.0001

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(
        loss = {'user_output': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'}, 
        optimizer = optimizer, 
        metrics = {'user_output': 'accuracy', 'binary_output': 'accuracy'}
        )

    return model

Here is the tf data generator:
def return_dataset_image_embedding(data, window_size=(224, 224), step_size=112, shuffle_buffer_size=1000, prefetch_buffer_size=1):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    image_paths = './data/'+df['image_id'].values
    label_user_ids = df['label_user_id'].values
    label_binary_flags = df['label_binary_flag'].values

    
    # Create TensorFlow dataset <<==generator output
    patch_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: preprocess_image_patches_image_embedding(image_paths, label_user_ids, label_binary_flags, window_size, step_size),
        output_signature=(
            (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32),  # Image patches
             tf.TensorSpec(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.int32)),  # User IDs as inputs
            (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.int32),  # User IDs as labels
             tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2,),dtype=tf.int32))  # Binary flags as labels
        )
    )  

    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)  # Shuffle data
    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.map(augment_data_image_embedding)  # Apply augmentation
    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (normalize_and_categorize(x[0], x[1], y[1])))  # Apply normalization after augmentation
    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)  # Create batches
    #patch_dataset = patch_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)  # Optimize for performance
    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=prefetch_buffer_size)  # Optimize for performance

    
    return patch_dataset

def normalize_and_categorize(image_patches, user_ids, binary_flags):
    """Normalize image patches and convert labels to categorical."""
    # Normalize image patches
    image_patches = image_patches / 255.0
    
    # Convert user_ids and binary_flags to categorical
    user_ids = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(user_ids, num_classes=len(user_ids))  # Assuming user_id range
    binary_flags = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(binary_flags, num_classes=2)  # Binary 0/1
    
    return (image_patches, user_ids), (user_ids, binary_flags)

The error says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/aimodels/common/prepare_data_vgg16.py", line 332, in <module>
    scores, history = model_fit_image_label_array(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/aimodels/common/prepare_data_vgg16.py", line 265, in model_fit_image_label_array
    history = model.fit(
              ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 244, in _adjust_input_rank
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Functional.call().

Invalid input shape for input Tensor("data_1:0", shape=(None, 3, 3), dtype=float32). Expected shape (None, 3), but input has incompatible shape (None, 3, 3)

Arguments received by Functional.call():
  • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 3, 3), dtype=float32)')
  • training=True
  • mask=('None', 'None')

What causes the shape incompatibility?
